# Giving refcount a minimum subscription count

Tags: rx-java

The [`refcount`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html) operator calls `connect` immediately when there is a subscriber. I would like to give it a minimum ref number to call connect if that subscriber count is reached. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [beta](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/index.html?rx/annotations/Beta.html), but [`autoConnect`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.1.0/src/main/java/rx/observables/ConnectableObservable.java#L95-L109) seems to be exactly what you're looking for:

(You would invoke it on a [`publish`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/publish.html)ed Observable.)

```java
public Observable<T> autoConnect(int numberOfSubscribers)
```